# interfacing Rust with Berkeley DB

Tags: berkeley-db, ffi, rust

I have an existing C++ program that uses Berkeley DB as a storage backend. I would like to rewrite it in Rust. Is there a way to write a Foreign Function Interface in Rust to use Berkeley DB? I have found the tutorial [Rust Foreign Function Interface](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial-ffi.html), but it seems too simple an example for the complicated C structs used in BDB; for example, to open a database
I need to declare a DB struct and call `DB->open()`. But I don't know how to do this using the example shown in the tutorial.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, looking into the C API of BDB I found out that it consists of C structures with elements-pointers to functions. It is not explained in the tutorial (which is very strange), but Rust currently supports [pointers to foreign functions](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2013/02/22/interfacing-with-c-functions-in-rust/). It is also mentioned in [Rust reference manual](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/rust.html#extern-functions).

You can create all required structures roughly based on the ones defined in `db.h`, and since Rust and C structures memory layout is the same you can pass these structures to/from the library and expect correct pointers to be present in them.

For example, your `DB->open()` call could look like this:

```
struct DB {
    open: extern "C" fn()
}

let db = ...  // Get DB from somewhere
(db.open)()   // Parentheses around db.open are needed to disambiguate field access
```

This, however, really should be wrapped in some kind of `impl`-based interface because calling extern functions is unsafe operation, and you do not want your users to put `unsafe` around all database interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sheer size and complexity of the DB struct, there doesn't appear to be a "clean" way to expose the whole thing to Rust. A tool similar to [C2HS](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/c2hs/) to generate the FFI from C headers would be nice, but alas we don't have one.

Note also that the Rust FFI can't currently call into C++ libraries, so you'll have to use the C API instead.

I'm not familiar with the DB APIs at all, but it appears plausible to create a small support library in C to actually create an instance of the DB struct, then expose the public members of the `struct __db` via getter and setter functions.

Your implementation might look something like this:

```
[#link_args = "-lrust_dbhelper"]
extern {
    fn create_DB() -> *c_void;
    fn free_DB(db: *c_void);
}

struct DB {
     priv db: *c_void
}

impl Drop for DB {
    fn drop(&self) {
       free_DB(self.db);
    }
}

priv struct DBAppMembers {
    pgsize: u32,
    priority: DBCachePriority
    // Additional members omitted for brevity
}

impl DB {
    pub fn new() -> DB {
        DB {
          db: create_DB()
        }
    }

    pub fn set_pgsize(&mut self, u32 pgsize) {
        unsafe {
            let x: *mut DBAppMembers = ::std::ptr::transmute(self.db);
            x.pgsize = pgsize;
        }
    }
    // Additional methods omitted for brevity
}
```

You can save yourself from some additional work by specifically calling C functions with the `DB.db` member as a parameter, but that requires working in an unsafe context, which should probably be avoided where possible. Otherwise, each function exported by `libdb` will need to have its own wrapper in your native `struct DB`.

Comment: Note that there is [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen) which removes much (but not all) of the legwork in binding to C libs.